# JavaScript - keyup event firing 3 times for every keyup (VuejJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am adding a keyup listener with `document.addEventListener("keyup", this.handleKeyup);` and it's firing three times for every keyup. Where am I off course?

My handler is:

```
handleKeyup(event){
  console.log("Fire!"); // logs 3 times for every key (?)
}
```

Comment: Do you detach the eventListener when the component unmounts ?
I am not sure how it can be done in Vue, but in React, we should detach any listeners attached when the component unmounts.

Comment: I am, in Vue is it's in the destroy or beforeDestroy lifecycle. However, this is all while the component is mounted.

Comment: Stupid question; Is this event listener inside a component that is used 3 times?
Some more code could be helpful.